# Make Android to handle a hardware keypad properly

Tags: keyboard

I got the following phone for Christmass: [GuoPhone N2](https://de.aliexpress.com/store/product/GuoPhone-N2-3-5-IPS-MTK6580-Quad-Core-IP68-Waterproof-Smartphone-1GB-8GB-Android-6-0/823792_32817830618.html) (also sold under the names Swell N2, Landrover N2, Cube1 T1C, ...). It has a build-in hardware keypad and runs Android 6.0. However, writing messages is quite cumbersome since there is no special software keyboard (like LG keyboard for LG Wine Smart) which would handle the keypad properly. I would like to be able to do the following:

1. Write "." by pressing 1 instead of searching through the list of characters.
2. Write space by pressing 0 shortly instead of holding 0.
3. Write numbers 0,1,...,9 by holding the corresponding buttons.
4. Switch input modes (capitals, numbers) by pressing # shortly.

Can I achieve this by changing the configuration files (e.g. /etc/system/usr/keylayout, /etc/system/usr/keychars) or do I need a special keyboard app? If there is no available solution of my problem I will consider downloading the source code of the Android keyboard from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/keyboard/) and trying to modify it. However, it would be a lot of work for me as I don't have any experience with programming for Android. Is here anybody who finds this task easy and could give me any instructions? 
Thank you very much for any help.

P.S.: I tried Swift Keyboard, Google Keyboard, etc... but they cannot even handle typing letters by multiple clicks so I can write just numbers with them. Only the preinstalled Android keyboard can handle multiple clicks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by installing Traditional T9 Keypad IME.